Elliptic regularity when the parameters depend on one variable
I am looking for references for the following problem. Let $\Omega=B_1\setminus B_{1/2}$, the open unit ball of $\mathbb R^d$ without the closed ball of radius $1/2$. Suppose that $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ is the solution of the boundary value problem
$$
-\text{div}\left(A(|x|)\nabla u\right)=0 \text{ in }\Omega,\quad u=\phi \text{ on }\partial\Omega,
$$
where $\phi\in H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$ or more regular if needed.
$A\in L^\infty((0,1);\mathbb R^{d\times d})$ is a (symmetric if needed) positive definite matrix valued function , with $$ A \xi \cdot \xi > \lambda |\xi|^2 \text{ and  }  A^{-1} \xi \cdot \xi > \lambda |\xi|^2. $$
Because the coefficients are radial, I think we should expect a regularity similar to the one-dimensional case, namely it should be that
$$
\| \nabla u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq \frac{C}{\lambda^{2}}\| \phi \|_{H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)}.
$$
This is most probably a consequence of the results of the paper  Michel Chipot, David Kinderlehrer, Giorgio Vergara Caffarelli Smoothness of Linear Laminates ZBL0617.73062 where they consider a more general problem, with a source (not a boundary value problem).
I am looking for a reference (if there is one) for this case.
